# Simplify if statement with multiple conditions

Tags: java

i am stuck to simplify such an if statement. The if statement in my Project looks somehow like this, but alitle bit more complex. There i have more if and if else conditions with multiple OR conditions.

```
private int testMethod(int a, char b, String s, float f, double d, TestClass testClass){
    if (a == 2 || s.equals("testString") || f == 5 || d == 4 || testClass.getName().equals("testName")){
        return 1;
    }else if (a == 3 || f == 10 || d == 1){
        return 2;
    }else {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

is there any way to simplify such an if statement?
thanks!

Comment: Hey! *FYI:* Are you aware of `|` being bitwise OR? Logical OR is `||`.

Comment: @akuzminykh: `|` is also logical when applied with Boolean operands, but not short-circuited. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2 - "Boolean Logical Operators &, ^, and |"

Comment: @JonSkeet Whoa, I actually didn't know that, thank you. I guess the first bit is used for `true`/`false` and therefore you can call it logical.

Comment: @akuzminykh: That's an implementation detail - fundamentally, if it operates on Boolean operands, it can't be "bitwise" as Booleans don't have bits, conceptually. Booleans are "logical" values, so anything working on them is logical too. (`!` is a logical operator too, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

If you can simplify this you can try this. But I think that your code needs in refactoring :)

```
private int testMethod(int a, char b, String s, float f, double d, TestClass testClass){
    return isaBoolean(a, s, f, d, testClass) ? 1 : isaBoolean(a, f, d) ? 2 : 3;
}

private boolean isaBoolean(int a, float f, double d) {
    return a == 3 || f == 10 || d == 1;
}

private boolean isaBoolean(int a, String s, float f, double d, TestClass testClass) {
    return a == 2 || s.equals("testString") || f == 5 || d == 4 || testClass.getName().equals("testName");
}
```

Comment: This is a good start. If you then rename the `isaBoolean` functions to something more descriptive like `isPaymentRecord` and `isTransferCompleted` (and revert to the `if` statement but using these functions), it'll already be way easier to read and write tests for. With many such cases, you can also wrap it up into e.g. a list of lambdas or matcher objects, so that `testMethod` is just a loop over them. PS: Wrapping all the parameters into a single `Input` object will make refactoring easier when you inevitably add another field to this pile.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I wrote this name of the methods because I don’t know what the verification data do, but for the author of the question your comment will be useful

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check with some boolean logic with the real conditions, but if you have a condition that requires `f == 5` or `d == 4` there's no quicker way to do it than `f == 5 || d == 4`